# Can't find the option to create a new Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am trying to create a new Maven project using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1. I am following [the Jetbrains help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-a-maven-module.html) for help.

Following step 1, I click on `File -> New -> Module`, and I'm shown an [option dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkuaN.jpg) without a Maven option.

I do have Maven installed, and I'm able to use it through the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have the Maven plugin enabled.

To enable it I went to `File -> Settings... -> Plugins` and clicked the check box with Maven. One restart later and it works fine.

Comment: Tnx. it Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

File->New->Project..., Maybe you will find out.

[image]

Comment: My picture I have doesn't show that option. I'm wondering why that option doesn't appear for me.


Edit: Sorry, misunderstanding, new project also shows me the same options. I still cannot create a Maven project.

Comment: Can you click `next` button on the right bottom?, if you want to `Create from archetype`, just enable this option.

Comment: The new project dialogue shows me [this](http://i.imgur.com/3NWo6Lv.png). Clicking `next` brings me to [this](http://i.imgur.com/P33w59U.png) dialogue.